# Can't locate node sick_tim3xx in package sick_tim3xx

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the SICK_TIM310 laser scanner using ROS Fuerte. I have tried installing the appropriate package from github using (I didn't include the https:// at the start because my karma is insufficient)

> svn co github.com/uos/sick_tim3xx.git

in my stacks folder and everything went fine until I tried

> roslaunch sick_tim3xx
> sick_tim3xx.launch

I get an error saying that sick_tim3xx is not a package eventhough it was in my stacks folder. As a result, I tried downloading the files in a zip file from github and unzipped it to the stacks folder and roslaunch works fine but I get the following error now;

> core service [/rosout] found

> process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [27496]

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [sick_tim3xx/sick_tim3xx]: can't
> locate node [sick_tim3xx] in package
> [sick_tim3xx]

So looks like it is unable to find the sick_tim3xx node. Could I please get some assistance on how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73447/can%27t-locate-node-sick_tim3xx-in-package-sick_tim3xx/) by [aviprobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/6004/aviprobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dido_yf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21158/dido_yf/) on 2014-12-18**:
hello, I have the same problem with you. Did you solve this problem? Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't build your package. Run `rosmake sick_tim3xx`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1